# ProgressBar.SetProgress crash in Android 6.x in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I got this class which does the animation for a ProgressBar:

```
public class ProgressBarAnimation : Animation
{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private float from;
    private float to;

    public ProgressBarAnimation(ProgressBar progressBar, float from, float to)
    {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
    }

    protected override void ApplyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        float value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime;
        progressBar.SetProgress((int)value, true);
    }
}
```

It works fine but crashed in Android 6.0.1, and I assume it will crash on all Android 6. Anyone got any idea?

I know the native Android got something like setProgress(int), but Xamarin Android always asks for 2 parameters so can't really fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: @Long, According to your description, you said the project works fine on other device, but doesn't work on Android 6.0.1? Can your provide a demo that can reproduce this issue here?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and seems like only crash on 6.x.x Lower version or higher versions of Android works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2-parameter method has been added in [API level 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int)).

For APIs below 24 use the Property `Progress` in Xamarin (they always try to replace the setters with properties).

Comment: Thanks man, that works. I figure out the 2nd parameter only crash on Android 6, works fine on Android 5 and 4 tho. Weird.